# data.table: Compare row value with group value

Tags: r, data.table

I need to do the following operation on a huge data set. So, is there a more direct / more performant way of checking whether a row value has a specific relation to its corresponding group? Following is an example, where I want to check by row whether the row value of `column` is the smallest for a given group and mark that in `new`

```
# df is a data.table
# first get the minimum value per group
df[, Min:=min(column), by=list(idx1, idx2)]
df[, new:=month==Min]
df[, Min:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reproducible example in OP, but my guess is this would work:

```
df[, new := (month == min(column)), by = list(idx1, idx2)]
```